# Best trick to strip wire in the middle (to connect elements in the middle)

Tags: wire, tools, strip

I have a simple 22 AWG wire that needs to connect to multiple elements. Every connection is a solder joint. I  would rather not cut up small wires, as it's for a batch run.

Normally I'd love to use daisy chained wire harnesses (google it) to connect some elements to a same wire, but this will not work in this application.

Is there a standard way to remove a bit of insulation from the middle of a wire?

Comment: Don't strip the wire. Use an insulation piercing wire tap. (google it). https://www.mcmaster.com/insulation-displacement-connectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've an automatic wire stripper like this:

[image: automatic wire stripper]

Picture from [SW-Stahl](https://www.swstahl.de/catalog/product_detail_view/id/7281/)

It basically does what [Peter Bennetts answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/622784/65584) suggests and cuts / pulls the insulation apart.

I've used it like you needed before and it worked quite well, but it will also push the insulation around. If you need a very precise spacing, it will be tricky to get that right.

Comment: This stripper works very well at the end of a wire but not in the middle of a longer wire as requested.

Comment: Unintuitevely, this worked really well! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Uwe: This was near the end of a wire, maximum sliding of the insulation is 20cm. It just works surprisingly well (stranded wire)...

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to actually remove some insulation - just cut the insulation all around the wire, then slide it apart at the cut.  The insulation will compress a bit, and slide along the wire, leaving a bit of wire exposed.

Comment: at 22awg, it can be hard to cut the plastic w/o the metal, and it's thin enough to be unforgiving.  heat makes it easier to cut/tear, stretch,  and smoosh the jacket and will lessen the time/care required whilst improving the success rate.

Comment: @dandavis It is a lot easier with solid than stranded wire and if you're going to be putting solder blobs along the wire you lose most of the advantages of stranded anyways. Might as well go solid and make things a bit easier.

Answer (score 6):

For small wire like that you probably just want to use an insulation piercing wire tap. For example, 3M 06129 Scotchlok 905 IDC Tap Connector.

[image]

(Original Picture URL: https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/507919M/3mtm-scotchloktm-instant-auto-electric-connector-905.jpg)

For larger diameter wires, there are actually insulation cutting tools that can flay the insulation and allow you to remove it from the middle of a wire.

[image]

(Images copied from here: https://jonard.com/cst-tools-round-cable-strippers)

Comment: A big advantage of scotchlok taps over solder joints in the middle of wire is that your insulation problem is already solved.  Tapping into existing wiring means you can't just thread on heatshrink, although on a new assembly that's not such a problem

Comment: For anything that's precious, please, remove the reference to the Scotch Lock. :-)) It's the single most unreliable connection mankind ever invented.

Comment: @Gábor impossible to inspect, wide variability, a million knockoffs with poorer quality or dimensional variances, whats not to like!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before when I had a wire whose ends were inaccessible and I needed something to hook an oscilloscope's probe around.  I used basic wire strippers like these:

[image]

I cut completely through the insulation in the middle of the wire, then made a second cut adjacent to it.  This left a thin "ring" of insulation that was no longer connected to the rest.  I then used an extremely sharp knife to slowly and carefully shave the top of the ring off (blade parallel to the wire, like you're peeling a piece of fruit).  The remainder of the ring falls off and you're left with a gap of about 1mm in the middle of the wire.

I've done this on several occasions and it's worked well enough for my purposes.  I wouldn't consider it production-quality, but for prototypes or one-off hand builds it's not *terrible*.  The main things to keep in mind is that your tools need to be very sharp, and that it's significantly easier to damage the wire than it is during a normal stripping operation.  I've only done this on solid wire, I'd imagine stranded wire would be too easily damaged by this process.

A few things to keep in mind:

- Gaps in the middle mean the remaining insulation can move freely back and forth, which can expose wire in unexpected places and risk shorts.
- It's *possible* to simply melt a section of insulation off with a lighter, but the resulting gaps tend to be very large (making the aforementioned problem worse).
- Solder joints have very little mechanical strength.  Use something like a [T-splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-splice) to ensure your connections don't fall apart.
- Insulating/protecting these T connections is very difficult.  You can heatshrink over part of it, but you may have to resort to something liquid like hot glue.

Comment: Please add a link or citation for the image that you copied into your answer. The policy for this site is that anything copied into an answer should have proper attribution.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - I knew I forgot something, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer about cutting two slots parallel around the wire then removing the insulation you want gone with a super sharp knife is the best.  I have been warned by so many professions to never use the clip type connectors. Simple reasons are, for what ever reason you will get a time when it won’t connect.  Secondly the clips often cut some of the electrical strands increasing risk of a short or having the wire break.  Taking a piece of insulation off a pice of wire between the ends is a tricky business. Take your time. Set up your job beforehand to get as much access as possible and if its not going rt take a break. Screwing up this job can really create problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the type of wire that is used for wire wrapping posts, you can compress the plastic insulation with a pair of pliers and easily peel it off, leaving the copper conductor unscathed.

Comment: I don't think you will find any 22 AWG wire for wire-wrapped applications.